# Does restarting the SharePoint Timer Service have any negative impact on scheduled or running jobs?

Tags: sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job, timer-service, owstimer

I have a custom SharePoint job that I created.  When I make updates to it, I restart the timer service programmatically to make sure that older, cached copy of DLLs are not used.  However, this design came into question recently, and I have been unable to find any literature to suggest that restarting the timer service will cause disruptions to scheduled or runnings jobs.

If this does cause a problem, is there an alternate way to clear the cache after installing/re-installing my job that does not cause adverse reactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recycling the timer service is not a big issue as it will cause the minor outage for a couple of seconds, During the Restart process, all the running jobs will go into paused state and jobs which are scheduled during that time frame will not run But will catch on next schedule once the Timer Service is back.

Another thing, there is Scheduled timer job in Sharepoint which automatically recycle the Timer Service every day 6 am( default scheduled). Read this blog to understand more about it.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2012/01/10/the-timer-recycle-job-job-timer-recycle/

Note: dont kill the timer service from the Task manager always use the script

Comment: am I understanting you correctly that by `restarting the SP 2016 Timer Service` will not have a big impact on 1000's workflow instances? Nor will it cause workflows to stop working or to cancell out or whatever?  There is an wf instance that is hanging in PROCESS eventhough its chilc wf has completed = suspecting due Timer Service. My fear is that if I restart the SP Timer Job, it will cause more problems!!! We run SP2016 on prem.

Comment: Can you also advise on the script for SP 2016 on prem - to restart the timer service? Also, why killing via Task Manager is not recommended?